# Json_decode не могу принять данные

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

Здравствуйте, проблема в том, что не могу правильно принять данные или может что еще, не знаю. Вот код приема данных:

```
if ($_POST['obj']){//Если з js пришла переменная obj(если obj существует) начинаем обработку
$obj = json_decode($_POST['obj']);
$distance = intval($obj->distance);
$date_in = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$date_out = strip_tags(date($obj->date_out));
$weight = intval($obj->weight);
$address = strip_tags($obj->address,'<p>');//Очищаем адрес от лишних тегов
$start = doubleval($obj->start);
$finish = doubleval($obj->finish);
$tarif = intval($obj->tarif);

$long_st=$start[0];
$lat_st=$start[1];
$long_f=$finish[0];
$lat_f=$finish[1];echo $myobj->searchMachine($weight,$address,$start,$finish,$date_in,$date_out,$long_st,$lat_st, $tarif);}
```

с js данные отправляются с нормальными значениями, но после обработки в php они возвращаются с 0 или пустые. В js все данные приходят, и он выводит все, но с 0 и пустотой, в чем проблема может быть?

Comment: 1. выведите значение `$_POST['obj']` перед `json_decode()` (вспоминаем про функцию `print_r`/`var_dump` и, если оно в браузер выводится, заключить вывод в `<pre></pre>`)

2. аналогично - с `$obj` после `json_decode()`

3. если понятней не становится (а ещё лучше ДО пунктов 1 и 2) - читаем, думаем: http://www.phpfaq.ru/debug

Comment: print_r($_POST['obj']) перед json_decode() еще показывает значение если посмотреть через ф12 в хроме, а print_r($obj) после json_decode() уже не показывает ничего

Comment: **Какое** значение у `$_POST['obj']` - нам нужно телепатически догадываться? Или всё-таки самостоятельно сможете проверить - является ли оно корректной JSON-строкой или нет?

А по ссылочке почитать всё-таки стоит, судя по вопросам.

Comment: оно есть строкой, там данные приходят типа такого: [49.00987979046978,29.40429082812501], вот и не декодирует нормально, как убрать скобки и разделить два числа в 2 переменные?

Comment: Да ёшкин корень, не "типа такого", а **точную строку покажите**! Впрочем, уже не надо - интерес долбиться в пустоту быстро проходит...

Comment: Вот это с ф12 в хроме {"tarif":2840,"distance":710,"address":"<h3>Чечельницкий район</h3><p>Украина, Винницкая область</p>","start":[48.14972013912109,29.316400203125003],"finish":[47.95821203652477,36.721185359375006],"weight":"464","date_out":"2014-06-18 19:37:06"}
а это с print_r($_POST['obj']): 
{\"tarif\":3112,\"distance\":778,\"address\":\"
Ð§ÐµÑ‡ÐµÐ»ÑŒÐ½Ð¸Ñ†ÐºÐ¸Ð¹ Ñ€Ð°Ð¹Ð¾Ð½

Ð£ÐºÑ€Ð°Ð¸Ð½Ð°, Ð’Ð¸Ð½Ð½Ð¸Ñ†ÐºÐ°Ñ Ð¾Ð±Ð»Ð°ÑÑ‚ÑŒ

\",\"start\":[48.2525431805904,29.492181453124996],\"finish\":[48.51599236982199,38.171380671875006],\"weight\":\"7657\",\"date_out\":\"2014-06-18 19:40:26\"}

Comment: Теперь проводим простейший эксперимент и пытаемся понять в чём разница:

    print_r(json_decode('{"tarif":2840,"distance":710}'));
    print_r(json_decode('{\"tarif\":2840,\"distance\":710}'));

Comment: это с js приходит в php: {"tarif":2840,"distance":710},
а это: {\"tarif\":2840,\"distance\":710} -  print_r($_POST['obj']) перед $obj = json_decode($_POST['obj']), потому что если пишу print_r($obj) после, то уже нечего не выводит

Я так понимаю мне нужно поубирать все слеши?

Comment: @Пашка Босой, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

По-моему, намёками тут говорить смысла нет. Будем в лоб. Что мы имеем в сухом остатке: путём простейших действий мы выяснили, что в функцию `json_decode()` передаётся строка, которая не может быть корректно декодирована. Посмотрим внимательно на эту строку:

```
{\"tarif\":3112,\"distance\":778,...
```

А как выглядит строка, которую мы можем декодировать? Да почти так же:

```
{"tarif":3112,"distance":778,...
```

В чём между ними разница? Очевидно, в экранировании некоторых символов слэшами (ответ на вопрос "почему это происходит?" пусть будет самостоятельно работой). Значит, перед преобразованием их нужно удалить. Путём минимального приложения мозга к гуглу находим аж целую готовую функцию с неожиданным именем, которая это сделает за нас: [stripslashes()](http://www.php.su/stripslashes). И пробуем:

```
if( isset($_POST['obj'] )
{
    print_r( json_decode($_POST['obj']) ); // не выводится ничего
    print_r( json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['obj']) ); // ура!
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало. Столько критики конечно, я первый раз работаю с json(

Comment: При чём тут json? У вас перед глазами есть есть ВСЯ информация для принятия правильного решения. Нужно просто научиться делать выводы из этой информации, иначе так и будете спотыкаться на каждом шаге и просить провести вас за ручку. Первая ссылка, которую стоит почитать на эту тему дана выше. Но не единственная :)

Answer (score 1):

PHP

```
$post_data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($post_data);
$id = $data->id;
```